# Unity - World canvas not seen in build executable

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, camera, rendering

I am working on a moba game in unity, with photon and i use world canvas to display the player life. In the edit mode, i can play without any problem, but in build exe, i can't see the world space canvas. i tried using other cameras, the only way i can see those canvases is to set a camera to render target and display the render result in a raw image. Here are the settings:[image][image]

Is this an unity bug? I am using the lightweight render pipeline from unity 2018.1.3. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've experimented depth-problems with cameras when I was working with online stuff with unity, try to move the canvas to a ridiculus Z, and tell me if you can see something.

Comment: What do you mean by moving to a ridiculous z? I placed a lot of world canvas in the world, because i was desperate to fix the problem. Even so, i could not see any canvas from any angle.

Comment: and the canvas order was set to 100 :))

Comment: hmmm...did you try to set everything on the same canvas?As I see, you got a couple of Canvas (just throwing ideas ^^)

Comment: I need two canvases. One screen space and one world space. the one with world space has problems. I think, in the end, i will try resolving with sprites instead of canvases. I really don't know why it's happening this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using 2D sprites

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Which game object did you fix by setting it to a 2D sprite? Was it an image import that you changed or a UI element?

Comment: I just changed from Canvas to 2D sprite. I have not changed any image